# Is there a story behind this "internet artifact" (result of mistyped SX SE url)?

Tags: discussion

I am often guilty of TUItmC (Typing while Under the Influence of too much Coffee.

Today I accidentally typed `space (dot) stackexchnage (dot) com` with stachexchange misspelled due to the coffee.  The result was a blank white screen with the words "it works" in largish font in the upper-left corner.

I wonder if this was an experiment, or an example of how to trap errors like this so they couldn't be canabalized by hackers or squatters the way `space (dot) stackexchange (dot) co` has been, or if there is a more interesting story behind it!

[image: it works]

Comment: Related side note - thefinalfrontier.stackexchange.com redirects to space.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just someone's web page in a domain that they registered:

> Domain Name: STACKEXCHNAGE.COM
>      Registrar: XIN NET TECHNOLOGY CORPORATION
>      Sponsoring Registrar IANA ID: 120
>      Whois Server: whois.paycenter.com.cn
>      Referral URL: http://www.xinnet.com
>      Name Server: F1G1NS1.DNSPOD.NET
>      Name Server: F1G1NS2.DNSPOD.NET
>      Status: ok https://icann.org/epp#ok
>      Updated Date: 26-oct-2015
>      Creation Date: 18-sep-2015
>      Expiration Date: 18-sep-2016
>
> >>> Last update of whois database: Tue, 24 May 2016 09:52:10 GMT <<<

The web site is hosted by Alibaba in California:

```
nslookup space.STACKEXCHNAGE.COM
```

> Non-authoritative answer:
>   Name: space.STACKEXCHNAGE.COM
>   Address: 47.89.51.203

```
whois 47.89.51.203
```

> NetRange:       47.88.0.0 - 47.91.255.255
>   CIDR:           47.88.0.0/14
>   NetName:        AL-3
>   NetHandle:      NET-47-88-0-0-1
>   Parent:         NET47 (NET-47-0-0-0-0)
>   NetType:        Direct Assignment
>   OriginAS:
>   Organization:   Alibaba.com LLC (AL-3)
>   RegDate:        2015-05-18
>   Updated:        2015-05-20
>   Ref:            https://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-47-88-0-0-1
>
> OrgName:        Alibaba.com LLC
>   OrgId:          AL-3
>   Address:        400 S El Camino Real, Suite 400
>   City:           San Mateo
>   StateProv:      CA
>   PostalCode:     94402
>   Country:        US
>   RegDate:        2010-10-29
>   Updated:        2015-05-18
>   Comment:        http://www.alibaba.com
>   Ref:            https://whois.arin.net/rest/org/AL-3

Could be used for nefarious purposes though...... (like phishing)

Comment: Not that [Typosquatting](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typosquatting) would ever make sense where a billion people are typing with ASCII as a foreign language. ...and the fourty what?